# Get hash value from url in laravel middleware

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2 with angular js. And also I have added a middleware auth for all my URL's.

I have a URL like this `http://localhost/myproject/public/#/resources`.

When I directly run the above URL it will redirect me to the login page and after login, it redirects only to the home page. Because there is no URL assigned after `public/`. But I need to redirect to hash URL.

Here is my Authenticate middleware code.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
        if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
            return redirect()->guest('login');
        }
    }
    $url = parse_url($request->url());

    print_r($url["fragment"]);
    //return $next($request);
}
```

I've tried to print fragment part of the URL. But I am getting nothing. Is ther any way to redirect with hash URL.